# Помогите с sql запросом в ActiveDataProvider и временной таблицей

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Мне нужно такой Sql запрос вставить в `ActiveDataProvider`, подскажите как?

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT id, username, text, sender_id 
  FROM pm 
  WHERE user_id =2 
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
) AS tmp_table GROUP BY sender_id
```

Дошел до этого

```
$subQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())->select('id, username, text, sender_id')->from('pm')->where('user_id =2 ORDER BY created_at DESC');
    $query = self::find();
    $query->from(['AS tmp_table GROUP BY sender_id' => $subQuery]);
    $query->with(['profile']);
```

Но этот код генерит такой запрос

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
      SELECT `id`
             ,`username`
             ,`text`
             ,`sender_id` 
      FROM `pm` 
      WHERE user_id =2 
      ORDER BY created_at DESC
     ) `AS tmp_table 
GROUP BY sender_id` 
LIMIT 10
```

Не работает из-за того что он ставит апотоф перед `AS` **`AS tmp_table GROUP`**.

---

вот весь код, тут где-то есть ошибка, может кто увидит

```
$subQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())
->from('pm')
->where('user_id = :user_id AND sender_id != :user_id AND status != :status ORDER BY created_at DESC', [
    'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id, 'status' => Pm::STATUS_DELETE]);
$query = self::find()->select('id, text, created_at, username, sender_id');
$query->from(['AS `tmp_table` GROUP BY `sender_id` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC' => $subQuery]);
$query->with(['profile']);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);

$this->load($params);
// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at, "%d.%m.%Y")' => $this->created_at,
]);

// $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'text', $this->text])
//     ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username]);

return $dataProvider;
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `$subQuery = (new Query())->select('SELECT id, username, text, sender_id')->from('pm')->where('user_id =2')->orderBy('created_at DESC');` и основной запрос `$query = (new Query())->from(['tmp_table' => $subQuery])->groupBy('sender_id');`  ... вот тут похожее показано http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html      https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md#yiidbqueryfromfrom-

Comment: Попробуйте `tmp_table` заключить в апострофы. Когда мне нужно было соединить таблицу с собой же, то я извращался так: `->innerJoin('(``table`` AS ``alias``)', ..., ...)` **(Двойной апостроф заменить на одинарный)**

Comment: @LANSELOT а зачем извращаться, если для алиаса делается так `'table' => 'alias'`    .... https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-query-builder.md#yiidbqueryselectselect-

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: LANSELOT респект тебе и уважуха!  апотроф помог!!!

Comment: только теперь когда в фильтре что-нибудь вводишь, кавычки не хватает
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `username` LIKE '%psy%'' at line 1

Comment: делаю так, но он ее экранирует
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'username', $this->username."'"]);
LIKE '%psy\'%''

Comment: два раза where появляется   
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `pm` WHERE user_id = 2 AND sender_id != 2 AND status != 2 ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS `tmp_table` GROUP BY `sender_id` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at, "%d.%m.%Y")='15.03.2016'